# Android ImageFlipper with Paths array

Tags: android, viewflipper

My problem is

I have a String array that has the paths to image files in a directory. I need to display the images like a slide show. I have been looking into the ImageFlipper and ViewFlipper.

Please provide me a solution as how to provide the solution. How to pass the images to ImageFlipper or ViewFlipper.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I was a able to figure out how to do it..... this is my code

```
String[] paths={"/mnt/user/Pictures/IMG_5509_LRS.jpg",
                                  "/mnt/user/Pictures/IMG_6076_LRS.jpg",
                                                    "/mnt/user/Pictures/IMG_5790_LRS.jpg"};
        FileInputStream in;
        BufferedInputStream buf;
        ArrayList<Drawable> drawablesArray=new ArrayList<Drawable>();
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray=new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        File file = null;
        final ImageSwitcher imageswticher=(ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher1);
         for(int i=0;i<paths.length;i++)
         {
              try {
                in=new FileInputStream(paths[i]);
                buf=new BufferedInputStream(in);
                Bitmap bMap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
                bitmapArray.add(bMap);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
              ImageView iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

              ImageSwitcher imageswitcher=(ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher1);


              for(int h=0;h<bitmapArray.size();h++)
              {
                  drawablesArray.add(new BitmapDrawable(bitmapArray.get(h)));
              }
```

Now I passed the drawable array to the Imageswitcher and got what I wanted.

Hope it helps someone.....